# EPPlus ToCollection<T> without manually having to map all class properties

Tags: c#, epplus

I have the following code:

```cs
void Main()
{
  List<Person> persons = new List<Person>() {
    new Person(){ FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", Height=180, BirthDate = new DateTime(2022, 10, 1, 13, 15, 30)},
    new Person(){ FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe", Height=173, BirthDate = new DateTime(2022, 11, 1, 18, 15, 30)}
  };

    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage("PersonsTest.xlsx"))
    {
        var sheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Persons");
        var range = sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection<Person>(persons,true,TableStyles.None);
        pck.Save();
        var table = sheet.Tables.GetFromRange(range);
        // !!!!! THIS WILL SUCCEED !!!!!!
        var personsData1 = table.ToCollection<Person>();
    }

    // NOW TRYING THE SAME BUT FROM A NEWLY OPENED EXCEL
    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage("PersonsTest.xlsx"))
    {
        var sheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets["Persons"];
        var range = sheet.Cells["A1:D3"]; //This is the same range as above
        var table = sheet.Tables.GetFromRange(range);
        // !!!!! THIS WILL FAIL (Exact the same code as above) !!!!!!!!!!
        var personsData = table.ToCollection<Person>();
    }
}

public class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public int Height { get; set; }
  public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

When I run this I get an ***ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Double' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'*** on the line:

```cs
var personsData= sheet.Tables[0].ToCollection<Person>();
```

**How can I get this working without having to map each and every member of the class?**

I understand that the following is working:

```cs
  var personsData = sheet.Tables[0].ToCollection<Person>(row =>
  {
    return new Person()
    {
      FirstName = row.GetValue<string>("FirstName"),
      LastName = row.GetValue<string>("LastName"),
      Height = row.GetValue<int>("Height"),
      BirthDate= row.GetValue<DateTime>("BirthDate")
    };
  });
```

But when you have a class with lots of properties this is not workable/desirable.

In the `EPPlus` documentation I only find examples that use the `ToCollection<T>` with an in-memory object like in the last example (`******* Sample 33 - ToCollection from a table ********`) of this [file](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus.Sample.NetCore/blob/master/33-ToCollection/ToCollectionSample.cs).

But I cannot find any example where the starting data is read from Excel (and not created in memory)

Comment: Do you get the same error if you set the Height property too type Double?

Comment: No, not on the Height, but then I get the exception on the BirthDate:
***Object of type 'System.Double' cannot be converted to type 'System.DateTime'.***

Comment: It is likely reading the birth date field as an Excel serial number date (e.g. 45019 = Apr 4th, 2023).  You can try creating a new property like so: Public DateTime Birthday { get => DateTime.FromOADate(BirthDate) } then change the BirthDate property type to double.

Comment: @JeremyHodge . That could possibly be done to prevent the exception from being thrown. But this is not the point.  The whole issue is that the `LoadFromCollection<Person>(...)` and its counterpart `ToCollection<Person>()` should work without having to manually map the fields.

Comment: The reason that ToCollection() is not working is because of the data type differences, which my previous comment should overcome, allowing it to work properly.

Comment: @JeremyHodge. No this is not true. I've changed to code example. If you look at the first ```using``` you see that the ```ToCollection<Person>()``` is just working successful, whereas the same code !!! in the 2nd `using` is not. This fails with an exception.